# How to call objective c method from c method iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, void

I want to call data from c => objective c (ios).

below I shared my code screenshot.

[image: I WANT TO CALL data from c => objective c]

Comment: Why are you creating c function in the vc class ? your all code seems objective c

Comment: I called CameraCaptureFromC from a c file.I am getting thisClass error.As it's self but this will getting error.

Comment: `-(void)cameraCapture{}` is an Objective-C method, and `void CameraCaptureFromC()...` is a C function. But when you do `cameraCapture()` you are saying it's a C function while it's not. Also, please do not post screenshot. First reason? I add to copy/write manually your code in the answer/comment to point out the issue. And clearly, developers are lazy. Also, images tends to disappears with hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare id referance variabe

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

id refToSelf;
```

than call using

```
[refToSelf cameraCapture];
```

Comment: Yes. This will help but  I am getting 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread"

Comment: @NovusMobile just call method in main thread.because if you are changes in ui related than all function called in main thread

Answer (score 0):

So far you have got correct lines. But you forgot to include .h file in your .c

Assuming you have `myiosclass.h` where you want to call `cameraCapture()` method present in the `mycclass.c` file.

In your `mycclass.c`

```
 #include "myiosclass.h"

    void cameraCapture(){
    //your c code goes here...
    }
```

In your `myiosclass.h`

```
extern void cameraCapture();
```

In your `myiosclass.m`

```
-(void)myMethod {
    cameraCapture(); //Called your C method.

    //Rest of objective c code ...
  }
```

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the current view controller as a parameter in you c method and use it

```
void CameraCaptureFromC(long cCameraClient,
                     const char *imageName,
                              void *object,
                  MasterViewController *vc) {
  NSLog(@"glfm:Camera Call");
  [vc addAllImages];
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  test
//
//  Created by colorsMacBook on 16/03/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 colors software. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    someMethod();
}

void someMethod(){
    printf("test123\n");
    [ViewController someMethod2:@"Calling objective C Method from C  method"];
}
+(void)someMethod2:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Message: %@",sender);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Console logs

test123
2017-03-16 13:22:02.858 test[1198:240019] Message: Calling objective C Method from C  method